# Glob Multiple File Types

Tags: rust, glob

I want to find files for some pattern with multiple extensions. Ex:-

```
some/path/**.{json,jsonc}
```

But rust [glob](https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/) function is not working with these types of patterns. Here is my workaround:-

```rust
extern crate glob;

use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    for file_name_result in glob("example/**.{json,jsonc}").unwrap() {
        match file_name_result {
            Ok(file_path) => {
                println!("Found:{}", file_path.display());
            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("ERROR: {}", e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Braces aren't documented as being supported in that way. I'm a little uncertain what the question is...

Comment: `glob` doesn't work with "this types of patterns" because they're not *patterns* they're [brace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Brace_expansion) shell extensions. They don't *match* anything, instead they duplicate the pattern for each expansion instance. At the shell level `foo/*.{a,b}` will be expanded to `foo/*.a foo/*.b` *before* globbing occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, `glob` doesn't accept this kind of pattern. You need to call it once for each extension:

```rust
extern crate glob;

use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    for file_name_result in glob("example/**/*.json")
        .unwrap()
        .chain(glob("example/**/*.jsonc").unwrap())
    {
        match file_name_result {
            Ok(file_path) => {
                println!("Found:{}", file_path.display());
            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("ERROR: {}", e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a pattern for this that might work if I have an unknown number of extensions provided at runtime?

Comment: Something like this might work (untested): `patterns.iter().map (|p| glob (p).unwrap()).flatten()`

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for more advanced use cases of glob, there is also the [globwalk](https://docs.rs/globwalk/latest/globwalk/) library which handles multiple extensions and exclusions.

> example/**.{json,jsonc}

Here is a code snippet from their documentation.

```
extern crate globwalk;

use std::fs;

let walker = globwalk::GlobWalkerBuilder::from_patterns(
        BASE_DIR,
        &["*.{png,jpg,gif}", "!Pictures/*"],
    )
    .max_depth(4)
    .follow_links(true)
    .build()?
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(Result::ok);

for img in walker {
    fs::remove_file(img.path())?;
}
```